# SwiftUI: How to go back to the previous instance in a navigationlink in a list

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I would like to code a multiple timer app for me and my family. And i would now like to show these multiple timers in a list. From the list the user can tap on a timer (list row) and than go to the selected timer. Like in this app:
https://youtu.be/KAIOYlXi2KE
So far I've already managed to generate the transition from my list to my timer view with a navigation link in my list:

```
                NavigationLink {

                    TimerView(timerObject: timer)

                } label: {

                    Text(timer.name)

                }

            }
```

But if I now go back to my list, and then try to go to the same timer which I started earlier, a completely new instance of my timer view is created even though I am still getting the print commands (every second) in my console of my earlier started timer. So how can I code that each list row has only a single instance of a timer and then always goes back to just that one timer? I would be really happy about help. Thank you!

Comment: Where does the `timer` that you pass to your view come from?  Creating a new instance of a view shouldn't be a problem as long as the timers being displayed are correct.

Comment: I do not know what you mean. My timer is just a simple instanz of a struct!

Comment: You are asking how to have one instance of a timer per row but you don't show what a timer struct is, how it's managed/stored, or how instances are currently being created.